# Python use like singleton style in multi thread but variable is independently

Tags: python, multithreading, singleton

I've been working on the singleton pattern recently, and I know that every class new by the singleton pattern is at the same address. But if I want use a way like singleton in multiple threads but the variables are independent, how should I implement it? A simple example like:

```
'''In test_1.py'''
from test_3 import SingleTonNew

class ADD_1():
    
    pp = SingleTonNew() #Is there a way i can import a class like SingleTon contain variables which are  independently in different thread

    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b
        
    def add(self):
       self.pp.a += self.b
       print("in ADD_1 a:", self.pp.a)
```

```
'''In test_2.py'''
from test_3 import SingleTonNew
from test_1 import ADD_1

class ADD_2():
    
    pp = SingleTonNew()

    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b
        self.ggg = ADD_1(b)
        self.ggg.add()

    def add(self):
        self.pp.a += self.b
        print("in ADD_2 a:", self.pp.a)
```

```
'''In test_3.py'''

class SingleTonNew():  

    _instance = None
    a = 5

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs): 
        if cls._instance is None: 
            cls._instance = super().__new__(cls) 
        return cls._instance
```

```
'''Main.py'''
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from test_1 import ADD_2

def Main_Thread():
    i = [1, 2, 9]
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
        for p in i:
            futures = executor.submit(Main(p)) 

def Main(b):
    l = ADD_2(b)  
    l.add()
       
Main_Thread()
```

The result:

```
in ADD_1 a: 6
in ADD_2 a: 7
in ADD_1 a: 9
in ADD_2 a: 11
in ADD_1 a: 20
in ADD_2 a: 29
```

But I want like:

```
in ADD_1 a: 6
in ADD_2 a: 7
in ADD_1 a: 7
in ADD_2 a: 9
in ADD_1 a: 14
in ADD_2 a: 23
```

Thanks to everyone who answered the question!

Comment: You could imagine a two step construct: one true singleton is shared by all threads, but it contains a dictionary keyed by the thread id where the values are the actual objects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the purpose of this but you can get the desired output that you want by resetting the value of a in the add function under the ADD_2 class like this:

```
class ADD_2():
    
    pp = SingleTonNew()

    def __init__(self, b):
        self.b = b
        self.ggg = ADD_1(b)
        self.ggg.add()

    def add(self):
        self.pp.a += self.b
        print("in ADD_2 a:", self.pp.a)
        self.pp.a = 5
```